# Trouble implementing iTextSharp to convert HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

Edit: Perfect solution was proposed below (streams closed in wrong order). I ended up going with an open-source alternative of PreMailer.Net + HtmlAgilityPack + wkHTMLtoPDF as it better fit my needs.

I am attempting to implemnt iTextSharp in C# to convert HTML to a PDF file, including converting relative URI's for Links and Images. I have a very basic implementation of "Changing the Default Configuration"(http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html), converted from Java to C#, to try things out. However, the sample HTML (which I have tested) which I feed into my script returns the following contents in the PDF I created when edited via a text editor:

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
```

This seems wrong. Also, the MemoryStream has a very small number of bytes associated with it. Is something wrong with my implementation of iTextSharp, or am I using streams or other C# constructs incorrectly?

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml.html;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.html;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css;
using iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.end; 

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
        var document = new Document();
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream );
        document.Open();

        var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        htmlContext.SetImageProvider(new ImageProvider());
        htmlContext.SetLinkProvider(new LinkProvider());
        htmlContext.CharSet(Encoding.UTF8);

        var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
        var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, pdfWriter)));
        var xmlWorker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        var xmlParser = new XMLParser(xmlWorker);

        var inputFileStream = new FileStream("testHTML.html", FileMode.Open);
        xmlParser.Parse(inputFileStream);
        inputFileStream.Close();

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

        var outputFileStream = new FileStream("testOutput.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        memoryStream.WriteTo(outputFileStream);

        outputFileStream.Close();
        document.Close();
    }
}

class ImageProvider : AbstractImageProvider
{
    public override string GetImageRootPath()
    {
        return "testDir/";
    }
}

class LinkProvider : ILinkProvider
{
    public string GetLinkRoot()
    {
        return "http://www.examplesite.com/testdir/";
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for your time and help!

Comment: I don't see that you're writing anything to the `pdfWriter`.  What would you expect it to print?

Comment: I was expecting to print the contents of the HTML to PDF

Comment: But you get `testHTML.html` but never do anything with that data.

Comment: Turns out I was doing something with the data closing my streams in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You grab the contents of the memory stream before closing the iText `document`:

```
    memoryStream.WriteTo(outputFileStream);

    outputFileStream.Close();
    document.Close();
```

But only when closing the document, iText completes the output PDF, in particular flushing the contents of the current last page and adding cross references etc.

Thus, change your code

```
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

    var outputFileStream = new FileStream("testOutput.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    memoryStream.WriteTo(outputFileStream);

    outputFileStream.Close();
    document.Close();
```

to this

```
    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
    document.Close();

    var outputFileStream = new FileStream("testOutput.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    memoryStream.WriteTo(outputFileStream);
    outputFileStream.Close();
```